# Adding external header to Visual Studio project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I have just created a new, empty, console C++ project in Visual Studio 2012. I create one file called `main.cpp`, with the following code:

```
#include "myheader.hpp"
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Then, I right-click on Solution Explorer, choose to add an existing item, and then browse to the location of my file `myheader.hpp`. Once this is added, I see it appears under `Solution Items`.

Now, I try to build the project, but I get the error:

```
Error   1   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'myheader.hpp': No such file or directory
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the header is not in the project directory, you must use a relative path.

Example:

```
#include "..\..\SomeOtherDir\myheader.hpp"
```

Another solution may be to add `..\..\SomeOtherDir` to the

> C++ / General / Additional Include Directories

properties for the project.